# Android App Localisation - Downloading translations at runtime

Tags: android, facebook, xamarin, localization

I'm working on an app that needs to support a large number of languages. Instead of bundling all languages in the app resources, I want to be able to download the language when the user selects a new language from the settings menu.

The Facebook mobile app does this very well. If you are logged in, go to settings> languages > switch language > pick a different language.

I think Facebook are downloading these language resources, Because if i put my phone into airplane mode , it doesn't work ( prompted with try again, or use english as default).

Since the app resources can't be edited at runtime, i'm guessing Facebook are using a database to download the language , then load the translations from there?!

p.s i'm actually trying to do this in Xamarin...trying to understand the Facebook Android approach so I can implement it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know specifically about Facebook, but I know this technique is in use by some people -- I've seen presentations on similar setups from other companies.  There are a couple of obvious benefits:

- Reduce overall app size by not bundling 30 languages worth of strings.
- The ability to improve localized strings without forcing the user to download an app update.
- Better data about what languages your users are using.

When I've seen in presented (again, this was not Facebook specifically), it worked much as you suggested -- user selects the preferred language, app fetches a string bundle from the server, then starts using it. Once the language is set, the app can even periodically refresh the localized string bundle to get updates.

However, there are some downsides to be aware of, especially if the localized strings change over time.  It can make support tricky -- if a string has changed, a button (for example) might be called different things depending on exactly when the user was using the app.  It also will really put pressure on your i18n strategy and QA to make sure the UI looks decent with strings that might be changing frequently.

Comment: Thanks for this info Chase. Any link to these presentations? I know on iOS you can download a different language bundle at runtime. But for Android, the only way around this that I can see is to download the strings to a data base, then read them for there? maybe that's how Facebook do it? It just works so smoothly it's hard to tell if it's a DB or a a cached resource.

Comment: This is the one that I remember most clear, although it's pretty high level: http://lingoport.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Dynamic-Language-Delivery-for-Adobe%E2%80%99s-Mobile-Applications.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If you download localization files you will not be able to use the default localization support within Android.

If you do go ahead with this strategy (downloading of localization files), you will need to create your own class to manage this or alternatively, search for a library which does this for you.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I agree with you, but this doesn't really answer my question.